# Copying content between artboards in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, design-process

I often need to make banner sets that consist of anywhere from 6-14 different sized banners. A lot of these banners have the same text (which I put in smart objects to work faster) and the same or different images. The placement and sizes of these elements differ according to the banner size though.

I find the process of 'copying' the content from one artboard to another to go a bit slower than I'd like it to. I can't simply copy/paste, I have to duplicate the layer and then drag it to the right artboard in the layer panel. *Hoping I have closed all my folders or else I have to drag miles upwards ;)*

There has to be a better way!
Why can't I simply copy paste a layer anymore? I'm pretty sure this used to be the case in older versions of photoshop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always copy it through the Duplicate Layer dialog, which you can get by right clicking the item you want to duplicate in layer pane and select your other artboard as destination.

[image]

Comment: Ah I completely overlooked the part where you can select a destination artboard. That's something, but still not as fast as simply pressing cmd c > cmd v...

Comment: It is when you duplicate multiple objects this way. Just select few and do the duplicate thingy. They seem to paste in the relative positions, so all you have to do next is adjust.